# How do I speed up repeated calls a ruby program (github's linguist) from python?

Tags: python, ruby, subprocess, github-linguist

I'm using github's [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to identify unknown source code files. Running this from the command line after a `gem install github-linguist` is insanely slow. I'm using python's `subprocess` module to make a command-line call on a stock Ubuntu 14 installation.

Running against an empty file: `linguist __init__.py` takes about 2 seconds (similar results for other files). <s>I assume this is completely from the startup time of Ruby</s>. As @MartinKonecny points out, it seems that it is the linguist program itself.

Is there some way to speed this process up -- or a way to bundle the calls together?

Comment: It seems unlikely that it would take the better part of two seconds to start up ruby; it takes 0.05s on my laptop which is nothing special.

Comment: How long does `subprocess.call(['ruby', '-e', 'puts "hello"'])` take? I doubt it's the ruby interpreter, perhaps the linquist library.

Comment: @MartinKonecny That is very fast (~0.01 sec per call), suggesting that it is the library itself, not the ruby interpreter. I can't tell if `linguist` is slow or if it is the startup of the library. Surely github itself doesn't take 2 seconds per file whenever a new repo is pushed...

Comment: what happens if you pass it directory with many files? How long does it take?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The script only takes a single file at a time (at least from the command-line). Any glob "*" fails. I think it is supposed to be called from other Ruby programs, not run from somewhere external. I didn't try a directory as input however.

Comment: as @nneonneo correctly points out, the directory probably should be a git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to just adapt the `linguist` program (https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/bin/linguist) to take multiple paths on the command-line. It requires mucking with a bit of Ruby, sure, but it would make it possible to pass multiple files without the startup overhead of Linguist each time.

A script this simple could suffice:

```
require 'linguist/file_blob'
ARGV.each do |path|
  blob = Linguist::FileBlob.new(path, Dir.pwd)
  # print out blob.name, blob.language, blob.sloc, etc.
end
```

Comment: as far as I can see, `linguist` may accept a directory

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: actually, it accepts a git repo (this is github software after all), so if you don't have your code in a git repo, it probably won't work.

Comment: @nneonneo I see. It accepts (single) files outside a repo, but I'll try it when I'm at a proper computer if can glob a repo directory. Thanks for the script, _"A script this simple"_ is not when you've never looked at Ruby code before!